# How to read the stdout/stderr of the background process ever if it ran long time ago?

Tags: linux

I have a java process running in the background on my linux server. 
This process is created by crontab. I know how to dump the thread informatnions to stdout.
Just to send signal:

> kill -QUIT [java_process_id]

However, I have no idea where to read the stdout/stderr of the background process.
Is it possible to read the stdout/stderr of the background process ever ran ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you did not redirect the output in the command, crontab will mail any output to the user who owns the crontab by default (probably root).  Log in as the owner and see if you get the "you have unread mail" message.   If so, your output is waiting there.

For reference, you can specify a MAILTO variable in the crontab to override who gets the message.  Checkout the man page.